# Tool for Reviewing Source Code

Tags: source-code

I'm looking for a tool that can read and compare between two source code for instance.

```
private void Test()
{

int = 1;

}
```

is same as

```
private void Test()
{

    int = 1;

  }
```

But it is a different between

```
private void test()
{

int = 1;

}
```

and

```
private void Test()
{

    int = 1;

  }
```

Do you know a recommended software?

If possible, if would be greate to know a software in open source, freeware or commercial?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note `int = 1` is *not* valid C/C++ and I don't think it is even valid java.

Comment: Is this supposed to be for arbitrary languages, or are you looking to support for specific languages (which might get you better answers)

Comment: If possible both of them

Comment: Do you just want to compare text files while ignoring whitespace differences?

Comment: both of them would be great

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend taking a look at [Review Board](https://www.reviewboard.org/), *free and open source but with commercial support* but it will not tell you that the example you give is different in the second case, *your compiler and linker will however.*

If, however, you are just looking to compare code files in a manner that ignores whitespace differences then many file compare utilities have an option to ignore whitespace differences.

Personally I like [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) *also free and open source* which does have this option as well as many others but there are a lot of file compare utilities available.